# How to mix Hadoop ChainMapper with MultipleInputs

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have hadoop job that joins two types of entities. The map step does some filtering, calculations and produces proper key-value records for later join. Hadoop MultipleInputs works fine in that case.

The part of the map logic can be reused in another context, so I am looking for a solution to chain different mappers. The default one I see is ChainMapper. However I am not yet clear how can I mix it with MultipleInputs having separate chain for each input.

Please let me know if smb faced the same issue and has some thoughts, ideas or even examples on how to achieve that. Thank you!

I keep going through Hadoop source and it looks like each Mapper in ChainMapper is run in a separate thread. This looks like overhead in my case. It would be enough if context.write in first mapper directly calls map method in the second.

Example:
There are monkeys and bananas at a location.

```
class Banana {
   location
   class
   mature
}

class Monkey {
   location
   type
}

YellowBananaMapper { filter out non yellow }
MatureBananaMapper { filter out non mature }
BananaByLocation { map banana to location -> banana }
MonkeyByLocation { map monkey to location -> monkey }
```

If I have question: Where are enough yellow bananas for monkeys?
I would do: Monkeys: MonkeyByLocation; Bananas: YellowBananaMapper -> BananaByLocation.

If I am asked to list yellow mature bananas,
I would do: Bananas: YellowBananaMapper -> MatureBananaMapper.

PS.

I've read about Pig and Hive and this is not a solution in my case as I am forced to use java MR jobs.